# Minikube with Ingress local image configuration

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, minikube

When I use my NodePort service I can get to my app. But when I try to hit it by Ingress I always get HTTP 404.
That not happen with test image `gcr.io/google-samples/hello-app:1.0` from this image I have response. 
This is my Deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
 name: app-backend-deployment
 labels:
  app: app-backend
spec:
 replicas: 1
 selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: app-backend
 template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app-backend
    spec:
     containers:
     - name: app-backend
       image: go-app-backend
       ports:
       - containerPort: 8100
       imagePullPolicy: Never
```

My NodePort Service :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
 labels:
  app: app-backend-deployment
 name: app-backend-svc-nodeport
spec:
 type: NodePort
 ports:
 - port: 8020
   protocol: TCP
   targetPort: 8100
 selector:
  app: app-backend
```

In that point when I call `$ minikube service church-backend-svc-nodeport --url` I get address where my app works.

But when I try to configure my app to get the route on Ingress it didn't work:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
 annotations:
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
 name: app-backend-ingress
spec:
 rules:
 - host: app-backend.io
   http:
     paths:
       - backend:
          serviceName: app-backend-svc-nodeport
          servicePort: 8020
         path: /backend
```

But when I do a configuration with example hello word app *(https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/)*  and replace everything in ingress.yml everything works great. Can anyone look at this and tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, you need to put in ingress under backend `path: /backend(/|$)(.*)` and in metadata `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2`

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
  name: app-backend-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: app-backend.io
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
        serviceName: app-backend-svc-nodeport
        servicePort: 8020
        path: /backend(/|$)(.*)
```

Comment: hmm works, thanks! Can you explain what you have done? And this is works strange. I have h2 database on it and it should work on `app-backend.io/backend/h2` but it work on `app-backend.io/backend/h2/ `and also if I just put  `app-backend.io/backend` i still have 404 but I think its from minikube not from my app

Comment: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/ there is the answer but I don't really understand *rewrite-target*

Comment: in your original config nginx would understand that url `/backend` should be rewritten to `//backend` because you configured that `rewrite-target` should be =`"/" + $1` where `$1` is completely matched url (path) e.g. `/backend/about`... So instead I added 2 captures `(/|$)` and `(.*)` where first removes root path `/` or `<empty>` if we got only `/backend` path, and then in second capture it takes all chars until the end of path. This second capture ($2) is then combined with `/` as `/$2` in rewrite rule because first capture will take that `/` so we need to put it back.